# SSRS functions that can mimic SQL functions STUFF and FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have the SQL query below that returns a list of engine parts, separated by a comma for one row.

While this works in my SSRS report, I was wondering if this logic(the STUFF function and FOR XML) can be duplicated inside SSRS rather than SQL.

I'm hoping to do this so that I can apply different background fill colors to it within the report based on the data.

Here is my SQL query:

```
select engineId, engineName, builderId,
STUFF((
    select ', ' + qi1.partsText
            from engine.internalParts eip
            left join engine.engineBlock eeb  ON eip.logId = eeb.Id
            left join engine.buildSession ebs ON eip.sessionId = ebs.sessionId
            left join engine.partCategories epc ON eip.partId = epc.partId
            where eip.partListId = 123456
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS AllSelectedEngineParts
FROM engine.buildPlans ebp
left join builder.builderData ebd ON ebp.builderId = ebd.builderId
left join factory.mainFactory fmf ON ebp.factoryId = fmf.factoryId
```

This will return a list that looks something like this:

```
193384 | LZ1-A | 5834940 | camshaft, rings, valves
```

So rather than doing this STUFF/FOR XML PATH in SQL, I was wondering if SSRS had built-in functions that could do something similiar.

Thanks!

Comment: There is not built-in function in SSRS to get that output but you always can use custom code in your report to create your own functions and get the desired result. Let me know If you need further help.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta thanks.  I've written a few simple functions that I put in my report code section.  However I can't think of anything that would mimic the SQL 'stuff' and 'for xml' functions.

Comment: Share a sample of your dataset and the expected result. At a glance I think it is possible.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta the query above is what populates my SSRS dataset.  The sample row above is basically what the report looks like.  The report works, I just want to try and do some of the data manipulation in SSRS.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what is the data manipulation you require but if you mean concatenate column data in a single row (like STUFF does). I'd use a SSRS LookupSet() function to get an array of values, then iterate over it to concatenate every value. Hope this helps let me know if you need further help.

Comment: @alejandrozuleta I did look into the lookupset function, but I don't think it can handle the amount of joins that I do in the STUFF function above.

Comment: The JOIN/Lookupset would be able to emulate the concatenating into a single string but you would still need the subquery from the Stuff as a separate dataset since your parts data doesn't seem to be in the other tables.

Comment: @HannoverFist So just create a new dataset from the query inside the STUFF function..but without the STUFF and FOR XML?  Thanks

Comment: Yes - though you may need a column to relate the parts to the other query - maybe **EngineID**? (Are the parts unique to each engine?) Then use that field in the LookupSet function to filter it.